# SSRS Convert Int To String

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a field within my SSRS report that displays as 1.2.3.4 depending on the status.

I would now like to convert this to a string to make it more read able.

so 
1:Completed
2:In Progress
3:Canceled
4:On Hold

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to use the SWITCH() function in your expression.

Like so:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!yourColumn.Value=1, "Completed",
    Fields!yourColumn.Value=2, "In Progress",
    Fields!yourColumn.Value=3, "Cancelled",
    Fields!yourColumn.Value=4, "On Hold"
)
```

This is a good article on IIF() and SWITCH(): http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/09/14/adding-an-else-to-your-switch/